# Use javafx in eclipse and some erorrs happen

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling

I am trying use JavaFX in Eclipse to make a small game. I just finished creating the `Dirctor` class and initializing the stage but the code cannot run. My code and errors are below.

```java
public class Director {
    
    public static final double WIDTH=960,HEIGHT=640;
    public static final String BK_IMG_OATH="img/logo.png";
    
    private static Director instance=new Director();
    
    
    private Director() {}
    
    public static Director getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    public void init(Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane root=new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        stage.setTitle("Tank");
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(BK_IMG_OATH));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1133)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:627)
    at game2/application.Director.init(Director.java:27)
    at game2/application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1122)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

Hope somebody can tell me how to handle thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and error as text.

Comment: I found when I remove this line code: stage.getIcons().add(new Image(BK_IMG_OATH));it can run successfully.Why?

Comment: See the duplicate questions for help. Basically, your application can not find the `logo.png` file, so you get an error. If you can work out what the correct path is, then you can fix the error and keep that line.