# I want to create a class Index to control the home page but failed

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am trying to use javafx in the eclipse to make a small game
However,during achieveing the home page I met problems
Below is my code in the class Index

```
public class Director {
    
    public static final double WIDTH=960,HEIGHT=640;
    public static final String BK_IMG_OATH="img/logo.png";
    
    private static Director instance=new Director();
    private Stage stage;
    
    private Director() {}
    
    public static Director getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    
    public void init(Stage stage) {
        AnchorPane root=new AnchorPane();
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        stage.setTitle("Tank");
        //stage.getIcons().add(new Image(BK_IMG_OATH));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(WIDTH);
        stage.setHeight(HEIGHT);
        this.stage=stage;
        toIndex();
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void toIndex() {
        Index.load(stage);
    }
```

```
public class Index {
    
    public static void load(Stage stage) {
        try {
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(Index.class.getResource("/fxml/index.fxml"));
        stage.getScene().setRoot(root);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it shows errors below:

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.`

Comment: This is the same essential problem as your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588924/use-javafx-in-eclipse-and-some-erorrs-happen), except this time with a fxml resource rather than an image resource. And the solution is the same, you need to lookup resources correctly.  Follow the troubleshooting steps in the linked guide in the duplicate and also the link it provides to the Eden tutorial on locating resources.